# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}_N$ is a field if $N$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, field-theory

I know that $N$ being prime is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\mathbb{Z}_N$ to be a field.

I know how to prove that it's necessary but I'm not sure how to prove that this is a sufficient condition on $N$.

Comment: If $N$ is prime and $0 < m < N$, then $m$ and $N$ are relatively prime. So you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In this case, it's not too hard to check the field axioms directly. Alternately, one can show that $\langle p \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z$ for any prime $p$; in fact, this property is close to primeness.

Answer (score 1):

The key is Bezout's identity. If $1\le n< N$ then $n$ and $N$ are coprime, and we have
$$an+bN=1$$
for some integers $a$,$b$. Thererefore,
$$an\equiv 1\pmod N$$

This proves that $n$ (or, more precisely, the class of $n$ mod $N$) has multiplicative inverse in $\Bbb Z_N$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**  Prove  that any non-zero element from $\mathbb{Z}_n$  has multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Please can you explain the difference between necessary and sufficient for this.

Comment: Yes.  Suppose  that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is field  but $n$ is not  prime. Let $m=a \cdot b.$  Then $a\cdot b=0$   in $\mathbb{Z}_n$  and $a$ (  or $b$) has no inverse. We  get contradiction that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is field. Thus $n$  must be prime.